# usort callback function not valid name

Tags: php, usort

I'm trying to sort an array of word objects according to their highCharCount (find the one that has the highest value for highCharCount).  For some reason, I'm getting this error message:

```
Warning: usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'compare' not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\practicePhp\classes.php on line 48
```

I was reading [OO PHP usort issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083071/cannot-do-oop-callback-function-for-usort), but I think it should work for me, since the usort and compare function are in the same class.  I'm not sure why it can't find "compare".

```
class SentenceContentContainer {
    public $strSentence; //theSentence entered
    public $arrayOfWords = []; //words in the sentence
    private $num_words_in_sentence; 

    function __construct($strSentence)
    {
        $this->strSentence = $strSentence;
        $this->arrayOfWords = explode(" ", $strSentence); //get the array of words in the string
        $num_words_in_sentence = count($this->arrayOfWords); //count elements in the sentence
    }

    //function addWordToContainer(&$wordToAdd)
    //{
    //  if($arrayOfWords == null)
    //      $arrayOfWords = new array[]
    //  array_push($arrayOfWords, $wordToAdd);
    //}

    function sortHighestLetterRepeaterOfSentence()
    {
        if($this->arrayOfWords != null) {
            usort($this->arrayOfWords, "compare");

            //print it out
            foreach ($this->arrayOfWords as $key =>$value) {
                echo"$key: $value\n";
            }
        }
    }

    function compare($word1, $word2)
    {
        if ($word1->highCharCount == $word2->highCharCount) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($word1->highCharCount < $word2->highCharCount) ? -1 : 1;
    }
} //SentenceContentContainer
```

Comment: Your "compare" function is internal to class, but passing it to usort doesn't know that. You may find this relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312986/usort-function-in-a-class

Comment: If you want to use a class callback like this use an array of `[$this, 'method']` as such: `usort($this->arrayOfWords, [$this, 'compare'])`. If using it outside the class use `usort($instance->arrayOfWords, [$instance, 'compare'])` and make sure the function is public.

Comment: Does `usort($this->arrayOfWords, array($this, 'compare'));` kill the warning?   You still need to pass an array that tells `usort()` that the function is within `$this` class context.

Comment: [$this, "compare"] seems to have fixed it.  Thanks guys!! I didn't need to use array in front of it.